# Get Value of Variable stops appending on last call & sets result to only that last variable

Tags: applescript, mail.app, automator, automation, javascript

I have created a simple workflow in Automator to ask questions & send an email. I followed the tutorial at https://macmost.com/create-customizable-text-inserts-using-automator.html. This has worked for me in different usages, but in this workflow, I have an issue. Near the end of the workflow, multiple variables are retrieved using "Get Value of Variable" to create a message consisting of them all. As each variable is retrieved, it is added to the last variables. However, the last get value of the variable I use deletes all of the other variables which were previously shown in "results" and the result becomes only that variable.

I have attached an image for reference. As you can see it continues to increase (4 items, 5 items), but when the last variable is got, it deletes all of the other items & is set to 1 item.

I have tried deleting the ask for text/set variable for the last statement, and it results in the issue occurring on the "new" get value of variable.

[image: Get variable stops appending]

Comment: I just tested an **Automator** _Workflow_ with 6 each, **Ask for Text**, **Set Value of Variable** and **Get Value of Variable** and the **Results** of the last **Get Value of Variable** contained the _values_ the previous 5 and the _value_ of the last one. So in my testing it didn't drop anything. That said, not sure this can be troubleshot unless you include the complete workflow and a set of test data the produces the error for you. Also what exact version of **macOS** are you running. This way we can test under the same conditions and see if we get the same results.

Comment: Also, if you could upload a copy of your **Automator** _Workflow_ to a _file sharing service_, that would save us a lot of time trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kk3y746gam55eny/AAASB9Z1Zf-KE2PK_6Dkcb8wa?dl=0 @user3439894 Thank you! I have added the workflow here to assist in troubleshooting

Comment: I do not do much JavaScript, however, I noticed your **Run JavaScript** _actions_ are not returning _plain text strings_. I'd try setting it so they do returns just a _plain text string_ and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Never mind, I added _code_ for them to return _plain text strings_ and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Yeah it is strange, it's done the same way with the same scripts on the tutorial & another similar workflow I wrote, and they both work fine like the automator workflow you initially created

Comment: Okay just to test something out, I converted all **Ask for Text** _actions_ to **Run AppleScript** _actions_ that did the same thing, and initially converted all but the last **Run JavaScript** _actions_ to **Run AppleScript** _actions_ and everything worked. I then converted the last remaining **Run JavaScript** _action_ to **Run AppleScript** _action_ and everything worked. I did this because of the differences in how each _variable_ was being _saved/returned_. By making all the _variables_ the same _type_ (_class_) it worked. Maybe there's a bug in **Automator** when dealing with mixed var.

Comment: BTW I also did not look at the link in your OP as it I felt it wasn't germane to the issue in this particular **Automator** _workflow_. Note too that I was testing this under **macOS High Sierra** as you did not say what exact version of **macOS** your running.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind providing a copy of your workflow? I'm quite new to Applescript & my attempt to create ask for text prompts results in no variable being produced. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Running your *workflow* unedited...**

In the fifth **Get Value of Variable** *action*, when running the original *workflow*, its **Results**, with the *list* button selected, was, e.g.,:

```
(
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Hey") ]>",
  "What's Up?",
  "1-3",
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Full QA") ]>",
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("aren't") ]>"
)
```

In the sixth **Get Value of Variable** *action*, when running the original *workflow*, its **Results**, with the *list* button selected, was, e.g.,:

```
(
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Thank you") ]>"
)
```

When it would have beed expected to be, e.g.,:

```
(
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Hey") ]>",
  "What's Up?",
  "1-3",
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Full QA") ]>",
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("aren't") ]>"
  "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("Thank you") ]>"
)
```

Just to test something out, I converted all the **Ask for Text** *actions* to **Run AppleScript** *actions* that did the same thing, and initially converted all but the last **Run JavaScript** *actions* to **Run AppleScript** *action* and everything worked.

I then converted the last remaining **Run JavaScript** *action* to **Run AppleScript** *action* and everything worked. I did this because of the differences in how each *variable* was being *saved/returned*. Thus by making all the *variables* the same *type*/*class* it worked.

In the fifth **Get Value of Variable** *action*, when running the edited *workflow*, its **Results**, with the *list* button selected, was, e.g.,:

```
{"Hey", "What's Up?", "1-3", "Full QA", "aren't"}
```

In the sixth **Get Value of Variable** *action*, when running the edited *workflow*, its **Results**, with the *list* button selected, was, e.g.,:

```
{"Hey", "What's Up?", "1-3", "Full QA", "aren't", "Thank you"}
```

As you can see in the example results what's returned is a plain *list* of *text strings* not mixed as in the output of the original *workflow*.

**The end result was, e.g.,:**

[image]

While I can not say for sure, nonetheless, it looks like there may be some sort of *bug* with the *type*/*class* count when stacking more than five **Get Value of Variable** *actions* and why it does not fail when all have been acquired, set and retrieved when done using the same type of *actions*.

---

Here is a link for the edited *workflow*: [Send_QA_Mail_Test.zip](https://gofile.io/d/w3wQqo)

- **SHA1:** `dfdec5414d0d5e22c46ad444b7bb77f19b442a45`

Answer (score -1):

I had encountered same problem when some "Get Value of Variable"s were set after "Run AppleScript".
[image]
After all, I adopt workaround that is set "Run Shell Script" imedeatelly after "Run AppleScript".
In "Run Shell Script" just execute "cat".
[image]

Comment: This is not at all the same conditions as the issue of the OP, nor is it a solution to it either.